# Find out what packages/modules are included in a python package

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to find out what packages/modules are included in a python package

I download some python packages I want using this link:
https://pypi.python.org/simple/

I use the command

```
python setup.py --provides
```

But the result is always empty

Comment: this is interesting. My original thought is to just grep for import but maybe there is a way of doing this systematically. This would be useful for writing the "requirements" section of a package, so I'm sure this exists.